# Rails has_one association with multiple primary keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

*Ruby 2.6.5 on Rails 5.2.4.1*

### Current Situation

I've got a table of `Products`, and I'd like to associate products as compatible with one another. For example, Product 1 is compatible with Product 2.

When creating the first `ProductCompatibility`, I populate it as follows:

`#<ProductLibrary::ProductCompatibility id: 1, product_id: 1, compatible_product_id: 2>`

At the moment, I can perform the following:

```rb
    0> ProductLibrary::Product.find(1).compatible_products
    => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ProductLibrary::Product id: 2>]
```

But I would also like to be able to perform the following, without creating an additional record:

```rb
    0> ProductLibrary::Product.find(2).compatible_products
    => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ProductLibrary::Product id: 1>]
```

Currently, the above returns the following:

```rb
    0> ProductLibrary::Product.find(2).compatible_products
    => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ProductLibrary::Product id: 2>]
```

### Current Code

My models look like this:

```rb
module ProductLibrary
  class Product < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :product_compatibilities, ->(p) {
      unscope(where: :product_id)
        .where(product_id: p.id)
        .or(ProductLibrary::ProductCompatibility.where(compatible_product_id: p.id))
    }

    has_many :compatible_products, through: :product_compatibilities

  end
end
```

```rb
module ProductLibrary
  class ProductCompatibility < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :product

    has_one :compatible_product,
            primary_key: :compatible_product_id,
            foreign_key: :id,
            class_name: 'ProductLibrary::Product'
  end
end
```

### Intention

The `primary_key` in `compatible_product` is why I'm getting Product 2 when I request Product 2's compatible products (instead of Product 1).

What I'd like is for the `has_one :compatible_product` association to return products where the primary key is both `:compatible_product_id` *and* `:product_id`, but I can't figure out how to do that without writing multiple associations and compiling them in a helper method (which feels clunky and unconventional).

I'm not even sure it's possible, but it seems like it's along the lines of a
`ProductLibrary::Product.where(id: [:product_id, :compatible_product_id])`
which I couldn't get to work as association logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with, thanks to some help from @max

```
module ProductLibrary
  class Product < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :product_compatibilities, ->(p) {
      unscope(where: :product_id)
        .where(product_id: p.id)
        .or(ProductLibrary::ProductCompatibility.where(compatible_product_id: p.id))
    }

    has_many :compatible_products, through: :product_compatibilities
    has_many :inverse_compatible_products, through: :product_compatibilities

    def all_compatible
      (self.compatible_products + self.inverse_compatible_products).uniq.sort - [self]
    end
  end
end
```

```
module ProductLibrary
  class ProductCompatibility < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :product

    belongs_to :compatible_product,
               class_name: 'ProductLibrary::Product'

    belongs_to :inverse_compatible_product,
               foreign_key: :product_id,
               class_name:  'ProductLibrary::Product'
  end
end
```

I'll probably rename some things, and we may need to implement a boolean to drive whether a product can be compatible with itself (for now I assume not).

It's kind of what I was trying to avoid, but it looks like this is a correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `belongs_to` instead of `has_one`.

```
module ProductLibrary
  class ProductCompatibility < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :compatible_product, 
       class_name: 'ProductLibrary::Product'
  end
end
```

The semantics of `has_one` and `belongs_to` are a really common source of confusion but the difference is with `belongs_to` the foreign key column is on *this* models table and with `has_one` the FKC is on the *other* model.

What you are creating here is really just a join table and join model with the slight difference that both foreign keys happen to point to the same table instead of two different tables.

Comment: This is not an entirely uncommon scenario and you can encounter it whenever someone tries to a "friend system" between users and there are multiple tutorials and solutions to this problem.

Comment: thanks for the clarification on the difference between `has_one` and `belongs_to`, that's very useful. Switching it still doesn't quite get me there...  

What I'm seeing is still:
```0> ProductLibrary::Product.find(3).product_compatibilities`
`=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ProductLibrary::ProductCompatibility id: 2, product_id: 1, compatible_product_id: 3, deleted: false>]>`

which is correct, but I also get:

`0> ProductLibrary::Product.find(3).compatible_products`
`=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<ProductLibrary::Product id: 3>]>`

Comment: Yes, that can really be expected. You're doing `WHERE product_id = ? OR compatible_product_id = ?` which will of course return both rows.

Comment: Usually you would setup two has_many assocations. `has_many :product_compatibilities` and `has_many :product_compatibilities_as_compatible, class_name: "ProductLibrary::Product", foreign_key: "compatible_product_id"`. I'm not sure your approach of rescoping the assocation will work at all here as what you really would need to do is a different join.

Comment: Cool, understood. I think I have a solution now, which probably isn't ideal from a conventionality point of view. I'll post it as an answer once confirmed, but this has been very helpful.